# DJI Phantom 3 Custom Mission App, Delay Between Mission Steps:

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I am working on developing an app using Android Studio which pilots the DJI Phantom 3 drone in a certain pattern, taking pictures at certain way points. I uploaded the DJI Sample Code to Android Studio, entered an app key on the Android Manifest.xml file, and modified the "CustomMissionView" Code in the "MissionManager" directory in order to program the drone to fly in a specifed pattern. However, when I run this project on the DJI Simulator, there is a delay between each of the "steps" of the custom mission, sometimes the drone is idle and hovers for a few seconds without doing anything. I want to know if there is any way to minimize the delay between steps of the custom mission without setting flight speed. I suspect it has something to do with the `DJICommonCallbacks.DJICompletionCallback()`, but I am not sure. I am a newbie to Android Studio, so any advice would be helpful.

Here is some of the code inside the protected method DJI Mission in the  "CustomMissionView" Java file

```
LinkedList<DJIMissionStep> steps = new LinkedList<DJIMissionStep>();


    //Step 1: takeoff from the ground
    steps.add(new DJITakeoffStep(new DJICommonCallbacks.DJICompletionCallback() {

        public void onResult(DJIError error) {
            Utils.setResultToToast(mContext, "Takeoff step: " + (error == null ? "Success" : error.getDescription()));
        }
    }));

    //Step 2: reset the gimbal to desired angle
    steps.add(new DJIGimbalAttitudeStep(
            DJIGimbalRotateAngleMode.AbsoluteAngle,
            new DJIGimbalAngleRotation(true, -30f, DJIGimbalRotateDirection.Clockwise),
            null,
            null,
            new DJICommonCallbacks.DJICompletionCallback() {

                public void onResult(DJIError error) {
                    Utils.setResultToToast(mContext, "Set gimbal attitude step: " + (error == null ? "Success" : error.getDescription()));

                }
            }));

    //Step 3: Go 3 meters from home point
    steps.add(new DJIGoToStep(mHomeLatitude, mHomeLongitude, 3, new DJICommonCallbacks.DJICompletionCallback() {


        public void onResult(DJIError error) {
            Utils.setResultToToast(mContext, "Goto step: " + (error == null ? "Success" : error.getDescription()));
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The pause between each step is due to how DJI set up the custom mission. When you prepare a custom mission, it does not send any mission information to the aircraft itself. It does build the custom mission on the device running the app. During execution of the mission, a step is sent to the aircraft. When that step has successfully completed, the next step is sent to the aircraft. This causes the pause between each step. If the signal from the remote control to the aircraft becomes weak, the mission can fail from timing out.

Waypoint missions do not have this pause because the entire mission is loaded onto the aircraft when it is prepared.